# Spanish Babel causes accents in start of sentence to stretch cell height

Tags: tables, babel, accents

When the **first** letter of a sentence in a table cell has an accent, the cell height is stretched and it looks strange. This only happens when I use the Babel package (with Spanish) so I think it may be the cause.

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|}
        \hline
        AÁ  \\
        \hline
        ÁA \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Table cell height stretched]

If I remove `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` or replace `p{1cm}` with `l` the two cells have the same height.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's definitely a bug.

Comment: as egreg says it looks like a bug, an immediate workaround would be to use `\mbox{ÁA}` but you shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's definitely a bug in `spanish.ldf`. You can cure it with a patch:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\es@accent}{\leavevmode}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|}
        \hline
        AÁ  \\
        \hline
        ÁA \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, the best approach to typesetting Spanish is to load

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and the problem would vanish by itself:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1cm}|}
        \hline
        AÁ  \\
        \hline
        ÁA \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

(Thanks to Javier Bezos for remarking it; and also for fixing the bug.)

Comment: +1 for digging (will you report it, or should I?)

Comment: I'm hearing :-). I'll send to CTAN a new version of spanish tomorrow.

Comment: Anyway, you should use the T1 encoding, and this error and many others related to hyphenation will vanish.

Comment: @JavierBezos Surely T1 is recommended for Spanish; however, somebody might use Spanish in an OT1 document for small excerpts and not need hyphenation and so on, so this should be corrected anyway. However your remark is important and I'll add it to the answer.